# How to read websocket response code through automation scripts

Tags: java, websocket, network-programming, java-websocket

Suppose I have a resource that is hosted on a websocket server, and I wish to validate the response status code `101`, after the connection is upgraded, how and which libraries to use.
Im currently looking at `jayway response` library, when I connect to a websocket resource, initially it sends a 200 and then upgrades to 101. So code returns 200, I would like to know how this library can be used for websocket validation.
Sample code is :

```
String response =given().get()("https://www.ws.com:444/examples/websocket/snake.xhtml")
                    .getResponse().asString();
```

This returns a 200, but does not return the next response. I might sound a little rusty here, would appreciate if you folks have any idea how to extend it to get status `101` or if you have any other suggestions.

Also, this requirement needs to be extended to handle redirection `30x` status codes as well, assume a resource is protected behind an access gateway, when a request comes for this protected resource, the gateway forwards it to identity store for verifying the user, at this time a 302 is returned, once verified, request is sent back to access gateway from where user is able to access websocket resource.

Comment: Your question vaguely sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Malt Il explain it again I need solution to check status of accessing websocket resource through automation scripts Suppose you access a websocket resource on a web server, it initially responds with a 200 before getting upgraded to 101 status, I want to automate this

Comment: I understood the question, I'm just interested in the problem you're trying to solve. If you're trying to see if a websocket endpoint works, why not use a Websocket client to try to connect to the websocket resource? Or are you building a debugging tool for websocket servers?

Comment: I have tried to understand how a websocket endpoint works by launching the chrome browser network tool, that provides the necessary headers that explains the change in status. I would like to achieve the same through code, i.e., when I access a http/s resource, code should be able to display the response headers containing the status as well